# (TypeScript 5.0.2) Is possible to infer a typesafe to a json object after transform it keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm struggling with a question here. I didn't find if it's possible to do in Typescript...

The goal here is to get all the object keys and do some transformations but without loosing the typesafe feature. If I have an object with keys in dash case, I'd like to transform all the keys to snake case, for example. This is how close I could get:

```
// 5.0.2 TypeScript Version

type InputType = {
  'first-name': string;
};

function transform<T>(input: any) {
  const result = {};
  for (const key of input) {
    const parsedKey = parseKey(key);
    result[parsedKey] = input[key];
  }
  return result as Required<T>;
}

function parseKey(input: string) {
  return input.replace(/(\-)/g, '_');
}

const before = { 'first-name': 'Fernando' };
const after = transform<InputType>(before);

// INFO: This works but it isn't what I want...
after['first-name'];

// INFO: This is what I want, but it isn't work...
after['first_name'];

// INFO: The "output type" should be something like this:
//
// type OutputType = {
//   'first_name': string;
// };
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wvkqnw) what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (well, tomorrow... I need to go to sleep now ); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: No way you did that... I'll try it now and then get back here to tell you! Thanks bro!

Comment: @jcalz, This is almost exactly what I want in the end... I made some [changes]() on your code to achieve my goal. I don't know if you could do those changes better than I did... If yes, it'll be awesome! Thanks again for your help and please, write an answer for I can check as the write one.

Comment: You haven't linked anything, but I'm concerned that the scope is expanding; I'm happy to write up an answer to the question as asked, but followups in comments aren't great and should be moved to a new question if it's important

Comment: My bad hahahaha! This is the [changes](https://tsplay.dev/WoYYaN)

Comment: I might do it differently but if it works for you then it's fine.  As I mentioned, this isn't really an appropriate forum for followup questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a `KebabToSnake<T>` utility type to convert string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) from [kebab case](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kebab_case) to [snake case](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snake_case#English) by replacing dashes with underscores:

```
type KebabToSnake<T extends string, A extends string = ""> =
  T extends `${infer L}-${infer R}` ?
  KebabToSnake<R, `${A}${L}_`> : `${A}${T}`
```

That's a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) which uses [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) to parse and concatenate string literals.  It's a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) so it should behave well even for very long strings.

The way it works: it takes an input string literal type `T` and builds up or *accumulates* an output string literal type `A`.  If `T` contains a dash, it splits the string at the first dash into the left side `L` and the right side `R`.  Then we recurse by using the right side `R` as the new string to parse, and by appending `L` and an underscore to `A` as the new accumulated output.  If `T` does not contain a dash, then we just append `T` to the accumulated output and return.

Let's test that out:

```
type Test1 = 
   KebabToSnake<"a-bc-def-ghij-klm-no-p-q-r-s-t--u---v----x-----y--------z">;
// type Test1 = "a_bc_def_ghij_klm_no_p_q_r_s_t__u___v____x_____y________z";
```

Okay, so that looks good.

---

Then we can give `transform()` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature that accepts an `input` object of type `T`, and returns a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where each `string`-compatible property key `K` from `T` is [remapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) with `KebabToSnake<K>`, and each property value is left alone:

```
declare function transform<T extends object>(
  input: T
): { [K in Extract<keyof T, string> as KebabToSnake<K>]: T[K] }
```

Let's make sure that works for callers:

```
const before = {
  'first-name': 'Fernando',
  'number-of-fingers-and-toes': 20,
  'is-a-human-being-or-other-mammal': true
};
const after = transform(before);
/* const after: {
    first_name: string;
    number_of_fingers_and_toes: number;
    is_a_human_being_or_other_mammal: boolean;
} */
```

Looks good, the output type is the same as the input type except that the keys have been transformed from kebab case to snake case.

---

As for the implementation, that's mostly the same (except I'm using `in` instead of `of` when iterating keys; is yours a typo?).  The compiler is essentially unable to verify that any specific value is assignable to a complicated generic conditional type like `KebabToSnake<T>` or the remapped version of it.  Instead of trying to get the compiler to do something it can't do, we'll just tell the compiler not to worry about types by using [the intentionally unsafe `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any):

```
function transform<T extends object>(
  input: T
): { [K in Extract<keyof T, string> as KebabToSnake<K>]: T[K] } {
  const result: any = {};
  for (const key in input) {
    const parsedKey = parseKey(key);
    result[parsedKey] = input[key];
  }
  return result;
}
```

That compiles with no error.  And finally, let's just make sure that it actually works as advertised:

```
console.log(after.first_name.toUpperCase()); // "FERNANDO"
console.log(after.number_of_fingers_and_toes.toFixed(1)) // "20.0"
```

Looks good. The compiler knows the type of `after` and the runtime value agrees with it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Z+SdqP++DVYnQCQTw-6Zhx8Y4doQA-RA8AMSMOGoaAPDg3APLBJnaK9hjlCxH3YIxRnxKgxjQdIPygAAmAAGIClAPZh4IsOowPxUoIBECxiXI4A6iMCx2kQdo6NaVCmEmCAzx2C8nX0ChjAkPECS9dp6SvL0IFPXYACooE4xBuKMHkIygR9nw+eiIBHYR2BzJRQPAoxQjlUIYLYODQgQoFkJoaJdIg7ShUBRBQkIuisFuUj2AM-40Co-S6IYxBWmieA0DQVoIHxDsoAk3YkijUKIHnVo0DYelZJ4+dlIYVS33nYA0AAVTASBGAAYTVNdOWzKB9ikL8RTsAA5bgGoAEQAeUkeQ4rCxLktSuTGHnGz9MM4zTPMvL0lytAv2YUgE3pDJKuqg5JEw+cMM6oA)